# Sharpsnmp API difference for SNMPv2 and SNMPv3

Tags: c#, snmp, sharp-snmp

I am going to use shrarpsnmp library for develop Manager for SNMPv2 devices.
I don understand that kind of API I should use. For example I want call snmp get request to device.
Exist two ways to do that:

1)

```
GetRequestMessage request = new GetRequestMessage(VersionCode.V2,         
Messenger.NextMessageId, Messenger.NextRequestId, new OctetString("myname"), 
new List<variable>{new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0"))}, 
priv, Messenger.MaxMessageSize, report);

ISnmpMessage reply = request.GetResponse(60000, new 
IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2"), 161));

if (reply.Pdu().ErrorStatus.ToInt32() != 0) // != ErrorCode.NoError
{
throw ErrorException.Create(
"error in response",
 IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2"),
 reply);
}
```

2)

```
   var result = Messenger.Get(VersionCode.V2,
   new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2"), 161),
   new OctetString("public"),
   new List<Variable>{new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0"))},
   60000);
```

What's the difference between this two methods?
And which will correctly use SNMPv2, or can either be used?

Comment: In 1, you chose a wrong constructor. https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/blob/master/SharpSnmpLib/Messaging/Messenger.cs#L547 The source code of `Messenger.Get` can tell you which to use. Of course, even if you use the wrong constructor, it still works, and the negative impact is that some parameters are wasted.

Answer (score 1):

Messenger.Get is obsolete according to the developer Website.

https://help.sharpsnmp.com/html/M_Lextm_SharpSnmpLib_Messaging_Messenger_Get.htm

and here some info about GetRequestMessage

https://help.sharpsnmp.com/html/T_Lextm_SharpSnmpLib_Messaging_GetRequestMessage.htm

Comment: Thank you, I know about auto generated documentation for sharpsnmp. But difference not clear from that.

Comment: Alright, Lex Li probably will come here and he have more knowledge to comment, let's see :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Messenger.Get(VersionCode.V1,
                           new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2"), 161),
                           new OctetString("public"),
                           new List<Variable>{new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0"))},
                           60000);
```

This Request is for V1 and V2. Because authentication and privacy is not available for V1 and V2. So use this method for V1 and V2.

```
var auth = new SHA1AuthenticationProvider(new OctetString("myauthenticationpassword"));
var priv = new DESPrivacyProvider(new OctetString("myprivacypassword"), auth);

GetRequestMessage request = new GetRequestMessage(VersionCode.V3, Messenger.NextMessageId, Messenger.NextRequestId, new OctetString("myname"), new List<variable>{new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0"))}, priv, Messenger.MaxMessageSize, report);

ISnmpMessage reply = request.GetResponse(60000, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2"), 161));
```

Here you can see there is authentication and privacy is passed in Get Method because we are Request for V3 so authentication and privacy is required.
You can use this for V1 and V2 but it make no sense, because authentication and privacy is not required for V1 and V2.

For more, See [Here](http://www.snmp.com/snmpv3/snmpv3_intro.shtml) which are the new features added in V3.